# read snippet of file with regular expressions from text file in python

Tags: python, regex, string, file

I have a text file where I want to match the word `PATTERN` using a regular expression and extract the text between `START` and `END` (text file shown below). I don't want to match the `START` and `END` fields directly since  I have random data in that portion, but `PATTERN` remains constant so I can easily match this. I have a quick and dirty Python script that can match the pattern, but I'm stuck at the next step.

```
HERE IS MY PATTERN:


        IGNORE SECTION

**************************************************
START   1   2   3   4   5
  .     .   .   .   .   .
  .     .   .   .   .   .
  .     .   .   .   .   .
END     .   .   .   .   .



TEXT    FILE    CONTINUES...........
.
.
.
.

**************************************************
```

How do I tell Python to **read in the lines 5 lines below the pattern, and STOP when reading at the first empty line**?

Here's my script:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import re

pattern = r'PATTERN:'+'$'

count = 0
fp = open('fileinput.txt')
for line in fp:
    count += 1

    match = re.search(pattern,line)
    if match:
        print 'Matched text:', line, 'Line', count
        line_match = count   

new_line = line_match+4
```

I've marked the line I want, but can't tell Python to start reading the file from this point on, and exit when it hits an empty line. Any tips?

Comment: The `nt` variable is useless there.

Comment: Do you have to read the entire file before extracting the data you want?  It seems that the solution might be to break out of the loop right after the `line_match = count` with `break`.

Comment: @ChrisP I need to read the entire file at least once before I can match the regular expression, right? Once I get a match, I want to go 5 lines below and continue reading till the NEXT empty line. So in this case, I should get the text between `START` and `END`

Comment: Why don't you start counting from when you hit the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you actually need a regular expression at all, you can just use `endswith`.  Here's how I would implement it.  Its not extensible, but it does what you want:

```
matching = False
found = []
with open('fileinput.txt', 'r') as file
    it = iter(file)
    for line in it:
        if matching:
            if line.strip() == '':
                break
            else:
                found.append(line)
        elif line.endswith('PATTERN:'):
            for _ in range(6):
                next(it)
            matching = True
```

Since you know that `START` happens 5 lines after `PATTERN` there's no need to search for it, so instead I used `assert` to make sure that it is where expected.  The lines matching are stored to `found`, and you can print them out nicely with

```
for line in found:
    print line
```

Comment: This approach is great if I have `START` and `END` each time. I actually have random floats at those positions in my actual data. I just used `START` and `END` in this example to make framing my question easier. 
I want to match only `PATTERN` and directly look 5 lines below, without performing any checks. Then, from the `START` line, I want to continue reading till I hit the empty line below `END`.

Comment: Is there any way to use `for line in file` and ask Python to start reading from a particular line? I could easily use `readlines()[startline:endline]` but this gives me no way to specify a `break` when I hit an empty line. That's where I'm stuck

Comment: Didn't realise START and END were only placeholders - I've updated the answer so it should work now.  However you search for `PATTERN`, python needs to read the file at leat up to that point, so you don't really gain anything by trying to tell it where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Just 2 things though:
1. Is it really necessary to use the `with open(filename) as file` object approach? I've never used it before and have no idea how it works

2. I work with a lot of Python newbies around me, so how can I ensure my code is readable and clean and can be customized?

Comment: Its good practice to make sure the file gets closed, and it is really quite a basic statement.

Comment: the logic is simple enough. I guess I could just use comments to describe what the `with` and `iter` statements do

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your explanations quite well; from what I was able to understand, you need to:

1) read a file from a specific pattern till an empty line;
2) match the portion read against a multiline pattern.

To achieve this:

1) read all the text of interest into a single variable with `readline()`, `readlines()`, `xreadlines()` or `for line in file` - whatever is the most convenient.
Note that `for line if file` loop can be stopped with `break` at any time and `xreadlines()` - just stopped to be read from. Next time they are invoked, they'll start off at the current position in the file.
2) match it against a pattern containing `\n`'s or use `re.M` flag if you need `.` to match newlines.

```
for l in f:
    if re.match("PATTERN:\n",l): break
s=""
for l in f:
    if l=='\n': break
    s+=l
m=re.match("<whatever-pattern-matches-your-chunk-of-text>",s)
```

Comment: I had no idea that the `for line in file` approach continues from the same line the next time it is invoked. That's great. Is there anyway to start reading the file 5 lines below DIRECTLY without having to specify new regular expressions?

Comment: `for i in range(5): s+=f.readline()` reads exactly 5 lines into `s` from the current position in `f`. If you need to *skip* 5 lines, just read them without saving results anywhere. (Think of it: you *have* to read the data to see what position the 5th line ending is at, don't you? ;) )

Comment: for some reason the for loop you showed above isn't working. I get the following error:
`ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`
Is it something to do with later versions of Python? I'm using v2.7

Comment: Ah, yes. `xreadlines()`/`for l in f` do some internal caching so `f.tell()` isn't necessarily just past the text you got (although iterators behave as if it is). Guess you have to invoke `f.xreadlines().next()` or `iter(f).next()` (which is the same) instead of `f.readline()` since you started to use iterators. The internal cache is shared between all file's iterators (in fact, they all are the same object ;) ) so don't worry about missing anything.